What does "the war prompted him" mean here?
From John Le Carré's Smiley's People:

Stalin rewarded his loyalty by murdering him in the purges. Vladimir was born Voldemar but he even changed his name to Vladimir out of allegiance to Moscow and the Revolution. He still wanted to believe, despite what they had done to his father. He joined the Red Army and by God’s grace missed being purged as well. The war prompted him, he fought like a lion, and when it was over, he waited for the great Russian liberalisation that he had been dreaming of, and the freeing of his own people. It never came. Instead, he witnessed the ruthless repression of his homeland by the government he had served.

Does "the war prompted him" mean the war gave him an opportunity to promote to general or does that mean the war motivated him to fight for his dream of "the great Russian liberalisation"?

I believe this is a misprint. My copy has this line as

The war promoted him

A quote on Goodreads backs up that this is the correct version of the line:

In which case, the reading is literal: the war won him a promotion in military rank. Or possibly that his career and station were "promoted" by the fact he "fought like a lion" - quite possibly both.

@GarethRees the answer does quote a copy of the book that I checked myself. The goodreads quote is to ensure that it's the OP's copy that's wrong, not mine.
